# Create a [question-and-answer] tag

Tags: support, tag-creation

It'd be useful to create a "question-and-answer" tag to manage questions related to the format of information retrieval and knowledge management.

It'd be useful e.g. for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/is-there-a-qa-exclusively-for-wikipedia.

Comment: Can you link to any *existing* questions where you think this tag would be useful?

Comment: I'm not convinced your sample question is even on-topic. Even if it stays, if that's the only question the tag is ever used on, the tag will be auto-deleted in six months.

Answer (score 4):

If there was a web app called "Question and Answer" then the tag would be a good fit and need to be created for questions about it.

But since the example here is a tag based on a broad topic matter instead of a specific web app or website, it would not make a useful tag to have or create.

Comment: Also, Q&A would most likely be a meta-tag since many apps have Q&A sections, features, etc. about which someone may ask questions about.